# how to start from 1 in dataframe

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, anaconda

i have dataframe that i would like to start my row from 1 instead of 0.

For example, if you can see the picture.

[image]

Comment: this is almost-certainly an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); what are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the index to whatever you like, but it's probably easier to index from 0

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["foo", "bar"]})
>>> df
     a
0  foo
1  bar
>>> df.index = df.index + 1
>>> df
     a
1  foo
2  bar
```

Comment: got an error 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: you may need to use `.set_index()` then `df.set_index(df.index + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Use DataFrame.index and specify range from 1 to length(dataframe) + 1

```
DF = pd.read_csv("path")
DF.index = np.arange(1, len(DF) + 1)
```

Comment: this is giving me 'array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
       18, 19, 20]) '

Comment: `np.arange()` will give this output, you need to assign it to the dataframe